# Adding m value to points using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, distance, linear-referencing, point

I have used Points to line to create a polyline from a series of points. I want the points to have attributes with m values corresponding to the distance from the start of the line.

There is also a second series of points that I have created with Generate points along line. These points are positioned differently along the line and I want them to have m values as well.

I wonder, what is a good workflow to add m values to both the old points and the new ones in relation to the polyline?

Do I need to create new features (perhaps retrace some of my steps) or can I work with my existing features?

What tool(s) should I use?

Comment: Have you had a look at the linear referencing tools?

Comment: Yep. I have written a new question about this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277679/calculate-distance-to-points-along-line-in-arcmap

Answer (score 2):

In order to extract M values from a polyline to point, you can use the "[Locate feature along route](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/locate-features-along-routes.htm)" tool from the linear referencing toolbox. This can be done with the "old" and the "new" points, and the points do not need to be exactly on the route. Of course, this does not mean that your points will have "M" values, but you will have the "M" value of the polyline as an attribute value in your point dataset.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have tried Locate Features Along Routes but the data doesn't come out right. See my new question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277679/calculate-distance-to-points-along-line-in-arcmap