# Calculate distance to points along line in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance, linear-referencing, point

I have two shapefiles: a series of points and a polyline created from the points with the tool Points to Line. Both shapefiles have the same projected coordinate system with a linear unit in metres.

[image]

If you were to calculate the distance to the points along this line - which is what I'm trying to do - the first point would have a value of 0 metres and the last a value of closer to 40 000 metres (the length of the line). I want to gather these values in an attribute field or a table so that I can plot the points in a graph with the distance in metres on the x axis.

I have tried the tool Locate Features Along Routes but for some reason the data doesn't come out right. I have tried the tool with both the original line and a route created from the line with the tool Create Routes.

Input values (identical for line and route):

[image]

Results - line:

[image]

Results - route:

[image]

Do you have any idea where I'm going wrong and what I should be doing instead? Is there another way to go about this?

I use ArcMap 10.4.1.

Comment: Use start-end points to calibrate route first.

Comment: Your end goal is a chart. So are you open to using other tools? How about making a sample shape file available to play with?

Comment: FelixIP: Could you elaborate a bit? As I explained in the question, I did create a route with the tool Create Routes.
Werner: Maybe this weekend! If I haven't figured it out by then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ([Split line at vertices](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-vertices.htm)) for your polyline shapefile that you created.

The result is the line segments with each length.

[image]

This tool needs Advanced license of ArcGIS. And of course, there are other options.

To get a new table with the points id, joining line id and the lengths, You can use (Spatial join) between the points and lines shapefiles.

Comment: -1 because it doesn't answer question and misleading. Tool is available for advanced license only.

Comment: @FelixIP Sorry, I got confused and I didn't pay attention that it's just for the advanced license. But for the question about distance along line, it solves the problem well.

Comment: Remove down vote, after amendment. Still incomplete answer. How to transfer segment lengths to points table?

Comment: This also doesn't measure the distance along the line from the *beginning* of the line, as the original problem stated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still haven't had the time to try this, but it only works if the points are vertices on the line, right? So I would have to start by converting the point into verticles.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this very easily with Python, no need for any advanced licensing.  This function can be used in the Python window of ArcMap and/or saved as a standalone script for future use (you would need to make sure to import arcpy first):

```
def measure_along_line(line, line_rid, points, point_rid, distance, factor=1):
    """ Calculates distances at points along line from beginning of segment

    Required:
        line -- input line feature class
        line_rid -- unique id for line route id
        points -- points feature class
        point_rid -- id field that matches up with values in line_rid
        distance -- field that will contain distance calculations

    Optional:
        factor -- factor for conversion of units. Default is 1.  If feature
            class units are in meters and you want to convert to feet, use a
            factor of 3.28084.

    """
    # read all lines into dict
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(line, [line_rid, 'SHAPE@']) as rows:
        ld = dict(r for r in rows)

    # now get the measure along line for every point (measure distance is in same units of projection)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(points, [point_rid, 'SHAPE@', distance]) as rows:
        for r in rows:
            # first get associated line
            line = ld.get(r[0])
            if line:
                # now get measure distance from beginning of line to this point
                measure = line.measureOnLine(r[1], False) * factor
                r[2] = measure
                rows.updateRow(r)
```

Here is the example I used in ArcMap (note I used a factor of 3.28084 to convert meters to feet):

[image]

And here is the table afterwards:

[image]

And what the data looks like:

[image]

This is done by using the [arcpy.Polyline.measureOnLine()](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm) method, which does exactly what you're trying to do.